# How can I automate tts?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, automation, text-to-speech, xsel

Right now I have a keybinding that uses the xsel program to grab the contents of selected text and pass it to the festival text to speech engine:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsel |festival --tts --pipe
```

I want to have the ability to toggle a process that will allow me to have any text I highlight automatically spoken, and I want to kill and restart the process if I highlight something else.  Is this even possible?  I think such a tool would greatly enhance everyone's workflow.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 5.3.0-51-generic
Shell: zsh 5.4.2
DE: GNOME

Comment: I don't want to say "no", because it probably can be done, if somewhat hackily. You could implement something that watches the X selection buffer (XA_PRIMARY) and when its contents change, speak that. Of course that's not ideal, you 'd want to check for it being set ideally.

Comment: Thank you very much.  "Hacky" is fine. ;)